# Problem with ParametricNDSolveValue

Tags: differential-equations

I am trying to fit a model to some kinetic data using a system of differential equations and three parameters, Λ, μ and γ.

```
model = ParametricNDSolveValue[{r1'[t] == (1 - r1[t] - r2[t] - r3[t]) 
- (λ + μ)*r1[t] + 2*μ*r2[t], 
r2'[t] == -(2*μ + γ)*r2[t] + λ*r1[t], 
r3'[t] == γ*r2[t], r1[0] == 0, r2[0] == 0, r3[0] == 0}, 
r1 + r2 + r3, {t, 0, 20}, {λ, μ, γ}];
```

I need to fit the sum of the three solutions, r1+r2+r3, to the data. However, I do not get a numerical value:

[image]

and `FindFit` does not yield a parameter set.

If, however, I replace r1+r2+r3 with e.g. r3, in the expr field, a numerical value results.

Here is the trial data set:

```
λ = 1; μ = 1; γ = 1;
kineqns := {r1'[
 t] == (1 - r1[t] - r2[t] - r3[t]) - (λ + μ)*r1[t] + 
 2*μ*r2[t], 
 r2'[t] == -(2*μ + γ)*r2[t] + λ*r1[t], 
 r3'[t] == γ*r2[t], r1[0] == 0, r2[0] == 0, r3[0] == 0};
 r1sol[t_], r2sol[t_], r3sol[t_]} = {r1[t], r2[t], r3[t]} /. 
 Flatten[NDSolve[kineqns, {r1[t], r2[t], r3[t]}, {t, 0, 20}]];

 Plot[{r1sol[t], r2sol[t], r3sol[t]}, {t, 0, 20}]
 times = N[Range[0, 100]/5];
 data = Transpose[{times, 
 r3sol /@ times + r2sol /@ times + r1sol /@ times + 
 RandomReal[.01, 101]}];

 fit = FindFit[data, 
 Sum[model[λ, μ, γ][[i]][t], {i, 3}] /. 
 t -> ta, {{λ, 2}, {μ, 1.1}, {γ, 0.9}}, ta, 
 PrecisionGoal -> 5, AccuracyGoal -> 5]
```

Comment: `Sum[model[1, 1, 1][[i]][5], {i, 3}]`

Comment: However, it does not work directing in FindFit fit = FindFit[data, 
  Sum[model[\[Lambda], \[Mu], \[Gamma]][[i]][t], {i, 3}], {{\[Lambda],
     2}, {\[Mu], 1.1}, {\[Gamma], 0.9}}, t, PrecisionGoal -> 5, 
  AccuracyGoal -> 5]

Comment: I can't reproduce that because I don't have your data set.

Comment: Try adding `/.t->ta` after the `Sum[]`, and solving for `ta` instead of `t`

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: Thanks. I tried your suggestion, but it still doesn't work. I've added the trial data set to my question.

Answer (score 1):

Use `Through`:

```
Through[model[1, 1, 1][5]]
```

> 0.740525

```
Plot[Through[model[1, 1, 1][t]], {t, 0, 20}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Alternatively, add one more equation `y[t] == r1[t]+ r2[t] + r3[t]` to the system and solve for `y`:

```
model2 = ParametricNDSolveValue[{
           r1'[t] == (1 - r1[t] - r2[t] - r3[t]) - (λ + μ)*r1[t] + 2*μ*r2[t], 
           r2'[t] == -(2*μ + γ)*r2[t] + λ*r1[t], 
           r3'[t] == γ*r2[t], 
           r1[0] == 0, r2[0] == 0, r3[0] == 0, 
           y[t] == r1[t] + r2[t] + r3[t]}, 
           y, {t, 0, 20}, {λ, μ, γ}];

model2[1, 1, 1][5]
```

> 0.740525

```
Plot[model2[1, 1, 1][t], {t, 0, 20}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: +1. Thanks for the suggestions. To get a result with FindFit, I had to transform the three differential equations by using the variable substitutions r1, r2, r3->y,r1,r2.